# Is "The readers are not limited to musicians" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

What I would like to express is that the readers of something I wrote are not necessarily a certain group of people, such as musicians. And then I wrote "The readers are not limited to musicians" but now feel unsure of.

Would you please tell me if this sentence conveys exactly what I intend to say?

Answer (score 3):

Often, in times like this, we need more context to help you write.  I'm kind of assuming you might want to be writing this within the essay/article/book, and you're not writing something separate *about* the work.

Let's pretend I'm writing a book article about music.  In it, I do go into some detail on music theory, but my main focus is something else, like music history, music cognition, etc. I want *potential readers* to know this article is for a wide audience -- ***not just musicians.***  This type of comment occurs often in situations like this.  Here's two options:

- This article is intended for a wide audience -- **not just musicians**.
- This book delves into the spiritual basis of music theory and what that means to all of us as spiritual human beings.  This articles is **not just for musicians;** anyone who wants to discover a deeper connection with spirituality can benefit from understanding how the development of music theory has evolved in line with the development of spiritual thinking.
- This book will appeal **not just to musicians,** but to anyone who has an interest in music.
- **You don't have to be a musician to read this book.**  While I do cover some basic music theory, it's not necessary to know how to play an instrument or to remember the music terminology.  There will ***not*** be a quiz!

So it depends on what you are trying to say.  I wouldn't apply anyone's specific suggestion without carefully understanding what you're trying to communicate. (This includes my own suggestions!  Those sentences weren't crafted to be exemplary.)

Answer (score 1):

The option I may think is..

> The readers **aren't just** musicians (There are other people as well)

But wait for natives to come answer.

Comment: The original is OK as well.  (native AmE speaker)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock oh..is that so? Thanks! :)